# Rails: Persist params through an Unauthorized request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, parameters

This Rails project has an API side to send data to the iOS version of the app. It uses Devise::Lockable to lock user accounts when they fail login 3 times.

This is a strange edge case, but maybe not that uncommon: The situation begins with being *already logged in to the desktop version.* If I then go fail login *in the iOS app* 3 times, but then click the reset password link in my email *from the desktop version*, because I'm already logged in, the request for the edit_password_url gets unauthorized (because the account is locked) and I get redirected to the login page.

What are some ways I could have it still go to the edit_password_url while keeping the params (specifically the password reset token)? I'm thinking either:

- Skip authenticating the password edit page (seems bad, but I still haven't see how to do this)
- Create some series of filters that check requests then redirect back
  to the edit_password_url ... but how do I keep that reset password
  token?
- Alternatively, I could somehow force sign out of the user in the main
  app somewhere in the process of that user failing login through the API. But these are namespaced and under different controllers and I haven't found a way to force a sign out that way.

Answer (score 1):

There are several actions in devise where it redirects if there's an active session. I never liked this behavior and usually override it. If I hit a link, it's because I want to perform that action, after all.

For example, visiting the sign-in link, you might want to sign in as a different user, so you could override that action to sign out if it's hit directly, rather than redirecting. So for my example you would subclass `Devise::SessionsController`

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  skip_before_filter :require_no_authentication, only: [:new]

  def new
    if warden.authenticated?(resource_name)
      sign_out
    end
    super
  end

  private

  def sign_out
    # From Devise::SessionsController#destroy
    Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? sign_out : sign_out(resource_name)
  end
end
```

and override it in routes:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {sessions: 'sessions'}
```

Comment: This is so close, and I think it would work if I weren't using spree_auth_devise. Are you familiar? I want to edit my passwords controller to something similar you've shown, but the file starts like this: `Spree::UserPasswordsController.class_eval do` rather than `UserPasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController`. I put in `before_filter :require_no_authentication, :only => :edit` but it's still authenticating and redirecting. Any ideas?

Comment: You can extend `Spree::UserPasswordsController`, but you need to use `skip_before_filter`. `before_filter` (or better `before_action`) doesn't override previous declarations...Did you try that?

Comment: I see. The "skip" part seems unintuitive. So: `skip_before_filter :require_no_authentication, only: [:edit]` will actually skip the authentication?

Comment: This is the way filters work. A later declaration doesn't override, it just adds filters. You remove (or rather bypass) them by using :skip.

Comment: I'm sure it should be working. But it's like there's some authorization occurring before the before_filter. I have binding.prys all over the place, none of which catch and I just see 401 Unauthorized. Not sure at this point.

Comment: Let's say I can't skip authorization. Is there another way to persist those params along with the redirection?

Comment: So you're not seeing it hit the `require_no_authentication` method? That's odd... you can persist params by placing them into the session `session[:temp_params] = params` and then `restored_params = session.delete(:temp_params)`. If params are large you might have to avoid using a cookie store for the session_store (see `initializers/session_store.rb`)